# An angle inside a regular pentagon

Tags: geometry, triangles

A student sent me a question and I am stucked. I'd like to use classical geometry, instead of hard trigonometry if possible (can be trigonometric, but I'd like to not use scientific calculator; the only answer I got I need this), but I am in circles. The pentagon $ABCDE$ is regular. The answer is $48^\circ$ (I've constructed in Geogebra). Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: It can't be a constant number if you move a line CD. Otherwise, it should have a fixed position. I guess this pentagon is regular, isn't it?

Comment: @mathfux It does say so in the title line, though not in the question itself.

Comment: Now it's clear.

Comment: This was a really cool problem. Thanks for posting it! +1

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard, thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $G$ be reflection of $A$ about $EF$. Clearly $EG=AE=ED$ and $\angle GED = \angle AED - \angle AEF - \angle FEG = 108^\circ - 24^\circ -24^\circ=60^\circ$. Hence $GED$ is an equilateral triangle. So $GD=DE=DC$ and $\angle GDC=48^\circ$. Hence $\angle DCG=\angle CGD=66^\circ$, $\angle DGE=60^\circ$, and $\angle EGF =\angle FAE = 54^\circ$. So angles $CGD, DGE, EGF$ sum up to $180^\circ$. So $G$ lies on $FC$. So $\angle DCF = 66^\circ$ and by symmetry $\angle FDC=66^\circ$. It follows that $\angle CFD=48^\circ$.

Comment: Fantastic! Many thanks.

Comment: Your solution is beautiful! Thanks for posting it! +1

Comment: I hope you will take my imitation as sincere flattery: [How can I solve this geometry problem without trigonometry?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3611833/)

Comment: Very elegant and creative Solution. I have a question, if we change the angle 24° for 42°, will this process work. I have make some attempts and seems that this will be a different way.

Comment: @PaúlAguilar This approach certainly would not work for your problem since the position of point $F$ would be different than in the OP's problem. Another construction would be needed.

Answer (score 3):

Without loss of generality, let the sides of the pentagon be $1$. Also let $ \mid BF \mid =x$ and $ \mid CF \mid =y$.

[image]

Apply the sine rule to $ABF$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{x}{ \sin(54)} =\frac{1}{\sin(102)}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Next apply the cosine rule to $BCF$
\begin{eqnarray*}
y^2=x^2+1-2\cos(84).
\end{eqnarray*}
Cosine rule again, this time on $CDF$
\begin{eqnarray*}
1= 2y^2-2y^2\cos(\theta).
\end{eqnarray*}
Plug that into your casio (other brands of calculator are available) & you get $ \theta= \color{red}{48^{\circ}}$.

With such a neat final answer you certainly get the feeling there could be a much more elegant method ?

Comment: Many thanks for attention! My initial answer was similar to yours, but I've used sine rule more times. In fact, yours is better than mine (cleaner). But so I though as you... Is there a more elegant method? I am happy to say yes now, did you see the answer of timon92? Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the point T such that
 TE = SE = SB
 Be the angle SET = 60
 So the triangle SET is equal to time.
 On the other hand
 CTD = TED = ASE
 So the angle specified in the figure is proven (because I didn't have the right to post the photo)
 We know STC = 96 and because ST = CT
 So CST = SCT = 42
 So SCD = SDC = 66 and so on
 CSD = 48

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Comment: Many thanks for attention! I am not sure that I can follow your thought. Did you mean $F $ by $S $? Maybe a figure would be fine if possible. Thank you so much.

Comment: Post a question ... you will be able to attach a link to a photo ... we can copy that & edit it into your answer ... I need to see the diagram, I am not understanding your solution at the moment.