# Solve $\sin 84^\circ \sin(54^\circ-x)=\sin 126^\circ \sin x$.

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

> Find $x$ in degrees, where $$\sin 84^\circ\cdot \sin(54^\circ-x)=\sin126^\circ\cdot \sin x\,.$$

I tried to use trigonometry identities to transform the product in sums, but I can't simplify moreover. I know the result is 30° since I solved it in a calculator, but there must be an algebraic way.

For context, this equation comes from solving this problem:
[How can I solve this geometry problem without trigonometry?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3611833/690175)

Comment: Hint: $180=126+54$

Comment: What have you attempted towards solving the question?

Comment: I tried to use trigonometry identities to transform the product in sums, but I can't simplify moreover. I know the result is $30°$ since I solved it in a calculator, but there must be an algebraic way.

Comment: @PaúlAguilar: You should always include what you know about a problem as part of the question itself. (Comments are easily overlooked.) This will help people avoid wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.)

Comment: @user170231  How is your hint useful?  Do you have a solution based on this hint?  All the answers so far do not use your hint at all.

Comment: Where does this problem come from?  Is it from one of those [adventitious quadrangle problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langley’s_Adventitious_Angles#Generalization)?  If yes, can you present to us the whole problem?

Comment: @WETutorialSchool It comes from this geometry problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3611833/690175

Comment: I think this is a context you should provide to this question.  I feel like there should be a purely geometric proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

$$\cos36 = \frac {\sin108}{2\sin36}
= \frac {\sin36+2\sin36\cos72}{2\sin36}=\frac12+\cos72$$

to factorize the equation as follows

$$\begin{align}
& \sin 84\sin(54-x)-\sin 54 \sin x \\
& =\cos 6 \cos 36 \cos x - ( \cos 36+\cos 6 \sin 36 )\sin x \\
& =\frac12(\cos30+\cos 42 ) \cos x 
- \left(\frac12 + \cos 72 + \frac12(\sin 42+ \sin30 )\right)\sin x \\
& =\frac12\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2+\cos 42 \right) \cos x 
- \left(\frac34 +\cos (42+30) + \sin30\sin 42\right)\sin x \\
& =\frac12\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2+\cos 42 \right) \cos x 
- \left(\frac34 + \frac{\sqrt3}2\cos42 \right)\sin x \\
& =\frac12\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2+\cos 42 \right) (\cos x -\sqrt3 \sin x) = 0
\end{align}$$

Thus,

$$\tan x = \frac1{\sqrt3}$$

and the angle in the source problem is $30^\circ$.

Answer (score 0):

This solution unfortunately requires that the answer is known beforehand.  It only provides a proof that $x\equiv 30^\circ \pmod{180^\circ}$.

Let $\theta:=18^\circ$ and $s:=\sin(\theta)$.  We see that $$3\theta=54^\circ=90^\circ-36^\circ=90^\circ-2\theta\,,$$ so
$$3s-4s^3=\sin(3\theta)=\cos(2\theta)=1-2s^2\,.$$  This means
$$(s-1)(4s^2+2s-1)=4s^3-2s^2-3s+1=0.$$
Because $s\neq 1$ obviously, $4s^2+2s-1=0$ which means
$$\sin(\theta)=s=\frac{1}{2}-2s^2=(1-2s^2)-\frac12=\big(1-2\sin^2(\theta)\big)-\frac12\,.$$
Hence,
$$\sin(\theta)=\big(1-2\sin^2(\theta)\big)-\frac12=\cos(2\theta)-\frac12\,,$$
or
$$\cos(36^\circ)-\sin(18^\circ)=\frac12\,.$$
(From the result above, we see that $s=\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{4}$.  As $s>0$. we must have $\sin(18^\circ)=s=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{4}$.  This shows that $\cos(36^\circ)=\sin(18^\circ)+\dfrac12=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}$.)

This is equivalent to 
$$\sin(126^\circ)-\cos(72^\circ)=\frac12\,.$$
By writing $72^\circ=30^\circ+42^\circ$, we see that
$$\cos(72^\circ)=\cos(30^\circ)\cos(42^\circ)-\sin(30^\circ)\sin(42^\circ)\,.$$
That is,
$$\begin{align}\frac12\sin(42^\circ)+\sin(126^\circ)&=\sin(126^\circ)+\sin(30^\circ)\sin(42^\circ)\\&=\frac12+\cos(30^\circ)\cos(42^\circ)\,.\end{align}$$
Because $138^\circ=180^\circ-42^\circ$, we have
$$\frac12\sin(138^\circ)+\sin(126^\circ)=\frac12-\cos(30^\circ)\cos(138^\circ)\,.$$
Since $\sin(30^\circ)=\cos(60^\circ)$, we obtain
$$\frac12\big(\sin(30^\circ)+\sin(138^\circ)\big)+\sin(126^\circ)=\frac{1+\cos(60^\circ)}{2}-\cos(30^\circ)\cos(138^\circ)\,.$$
Thus,
$$\sin(84^\circ)\cos(54^\circ)+\sin(126^\circ)=\cos^2(30^\circ)-\cos(30^\circ)\cos(138^\circ)\,.$$
As
$$\cos(30^\circ)-\cos(138^\circ)=2\sin(84^\circ)\sin(54^\circ)=\frac{\sin(84^\circ)\sin(54^\circ)}{\sin(30^\circ)}\,,$$
we conclude that
$$\begin{align}\cos^2(30^\circ)-\cos(30^\circ)\cos(138^\circ)&=\cos(30^\circ)\,\big(\cos(30^\circ)-\cos(138^\circ)\big)\\&=\frac{\cos(30^\circ)}{\sin(30^\circ)}\,\sin(84^\circ)\sin(54^\circ)\,,\end{align}$$
whence
$$\tan(30^\circ)=\frac{\sin(30^\circ)}{\cos(30^\circ)}=\frac{\sin(84^\circ)\sin(54^\circ)}{\sin(84^\circ)\cos(54^\circ)+\sin(126^\circ)}\,.$$

If $x$ satisfies the given equation, then from $$ \sin(54^\circ -x )=\sin(54^\circ)\cos(x)-\cos(54^\circ)\sin(x)\,,$$
we must have
$$\begin{align}\sin(126^\circ)\sin(x)&=\sin(84^\circ)\sin(54^\circ-x)\\&=\sin(84^\circ)\big(\sin(54^\circ)\cos(x)-\cos(54^\circ)\sin(x)\big)\,.\end{align}$$
This shows that
$$\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=\frac{\sin(84^\circ)\sin(54^\circ)}{\sin(84^\circ)\cos(54^\circ)+\sin(126^\circ)}=\tan(30^\circ)\,.$$
Ergo,
$$x=30^\circ+n\cdot 180^\circ\,,$$
where $n$ is an integer.